# dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate build failed

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to connect .net core 5 with sql server but dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate buid fail and it says C:\Users\ccc\Desktop\dotnet-5-crud-api-master\Helpers\DataContext.cs(18,20): error CS1061: 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
for 'UseSqlServer' and no accessible extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (a
re you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\ccc\Desktop\dotnet-5-crud-api-master\WebApi.csproj]
how to fix it

Comment: Have you referenced `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in your project? Here you will find these `DbContextOptionsBuilder` extensions for SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions.usesqlserver?view=efcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. If you take a look at the docs you will find the [`DbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbcontextoptionsextensions.usesqlserver?view=efcore-5.0) extension method that you're looking for.